# Custom Validator won't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to force the user to choose to fill either the Photo or the Video `Textbox` using the `CustomValidator` but it's not working, I've tried searching around and from previous questions a lot of people instructed to add the `ValidateEmptyText="true"` property, I tried adding it but it still won't fire.

I'm using other `RequiredFieldValidators` which are operating normally.

**This is my `aspx` code of the two fields:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="+"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" PlaceHolder="Photos" ID="pics" ValidationGroup="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="+"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="vids" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Videos" ValidationGroup="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter either a photo or a picture!" OnServerValidate="ValidateBoxes" ValidationGroup="txt1" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**This is my `c#` `Validation method`:**

```
public void ValidateBoxes(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pics.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vids.Text))
        e.IsValid = false;
    else
        e.IsValid = true;
}
```

**EDIT :** This is one of the text boxes and it's validators from the output screen shots.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID ="city_in" PlaceHolder ="Enter city" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="city_in" ErrorMessage="Please enter the city!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**EDIT:** This is the whole `aspx` Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h1>
    Creating An Event
</h1>
    <br />
<h3>
    Please Provide the information below
</h3>
<asp:TextBox ID ="city_in" PlaceHolder ="Enter city" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="city_in" ErrorMessage="Please enter the city!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" PlaceHolder ="Enter date" TextMode="Date" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="date" ErrorMessage="Please enter the date!" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="desc" runat="server" PlaceHolder = "Description"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="desc" ErrorMessage="Please enter the description!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID ="entertain" runat="server" PlaceHolder ="Entertainer"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="entertain" ErrorMessage="Please enter the entertainer!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID ="viewer" runat="server" PlaceHolder ="ID"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:TextBox ID ="location" runat="server" PlaceHolder ="Location"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the location!" ControlToValidate="location" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<br />
<p>
    Please choose what type of Multimedia you would like to upload
</p>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="+"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" PlaceHolder="Photos" ID="pics" ></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="+"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="vids" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Videos"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter either a photo or a picture!" OnServerValidate="ValidateBoxes" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID ="btn" runat="server" Text="Create Event" OnClick="create_Event" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="go_Profile"/>
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: why not use JS?

Comment: Does your "Create Event" button have `ValidationGroup="txt1"`?

Comment: @kooshy I'm not familiar with JS tbh, I'm also quite new to C# and asp.net, I've used them for less than a week, and i'm using them for my university assignment, I did try to use a code I found on another question which was written in javascript and was written as a script in the aspx file but it also didn't work, Would you please show me an example? thanks

Comment: @mxmissile no, it does not, from what I understand I only need to add it to the fields that I want to force the user to fill or else He won't be able to proceed, and so far it's working with all of the other text boxes that use a RequiredFieldValidator, can you explain why would I add it? Thanks! =)

Comment: It is required, if you use any groups. Groups enable more than one "psuedo" form on a single WebForm page. You can either remove ValidationGroups altogether or add a second "submit" button tied to the group.

Comment: @mxmissile but, with the other text boxes that use a required field validator, the "Create Event" Button didn't work, instead the validators were fired, but that wasn't the case with the CustomValidator, Plus shouldn't I only add the `ValidationGroup="txt1"` to only the fields that I want to be filled, so even if i don't add it to the "Create Event" Button, the button still won't work because the page isn't validated right?

Comment: No, thats not how aspx validation works. Remove ValidationGroups from all your controls in this form, I'm *mostly* positive it will work then. You still want the other required field validators to fire right?

Comment: @mxmissile Yea I want the other required field validators to fire, do I remove their Validation Groups as well?

Comment: Yes, try it, all your validators should fire.

Comment: @mxmissile I removed the `ValidationGroups` from the 2 textboxes and the create event button, But it still submits even though I didn't fill out the video and photo text boxes, Do I remove the `ControlToValidate` from all of the other text boxes?

Comment: No, add one of your required fields and validators to your code above.

Comment: @mxmissile Okay, I'll add an edit

Comment: @Sorata I just noticed your "+" buttons, how are those involved? I'm sorry I missed those.

Comment: @mxmissile I've added it!

Comment: @mxmissile I was supposed to add more textboxes (either video/Photo) using them But I haven't added in functionality to them up until now Because I was working on validating the text boxes, I haven't written any scripts nor added anything in the .cs file for them yet.

Comment: I'm using your exact code above (without ValidationGroups), and when I click Create Event, `ValidateBoxes` fires like it should. Something else is missing.

Comment: What happens if you fill in the required fields, does your custom validator then fire?

Comment: I tried filling them out and then creating an event, But it still creates it, the custom validator doesn't fire (also sorry for the late reply I wasn't infront of my pc) I'll put a copy of the whole aspx code In an edit

Comment: @mxmissile Before the aspx code I linked is this line, I tried to include it but It's bugging out so I'll link it here, Sorry! `<%@ Page Title="Create Event" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Create_Event.aspx.cs" Inherits="Create_Event" %>`

Answer (score 0):

This code was tested and works properly.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p>
            Please choose what type of Multimedia you would like to upload
        </p>
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" PlaceHolder="Photos" ID="pics"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="vids" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Videos"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter either a photo or a picture!" OnServerValidate="ValidateBoxes" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Create Event"  />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </form>
</body>
```

with this code:

```
public void ValidateBoxes(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pics.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vids.Text))
                e.IsValid = false;
            else
                e.IsValid = true;
        }
```

[image]

if I enter any value in either of the two textboxes, the Validator is not shown.

I wanted to leave a comment but figured it would be best to display to you exactly what I tested this way you know what is working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the Page IsValid before creating your event...

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        Response.Write("Creating an event");
    }
}
```